# SQL: How to fix Error Code 1525 Incorrect DATE when using "where var like '19__-05-%'"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using select from

```
select *
from worker_info
where birthday like '____-1_-%';
```

it says

> Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: '____-1_-%'

How should I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In most DBMSs, `LIKE` only works on columns containing text, and a `DATE` column is not text (it's `DATE`). What you're actually trying to do is unclear, so it's difficult to suggest an alternative.

Comment: we can't use `LIKE` for 'DATETIME` , you can use either `IN` or `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help! It works.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are trying to match any birthdate which appears from October onwards.  So you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM worker_info
WHERE MONTH(birthday) IN (10, 11, 12);
```

The problem with your current approach is that `birthday` is a date column (the correct thing to do), *not* a text column.  So, comparing against a text `LIKE` expression does not make sense.  But, you can and should use the MySQL date functions instead.

Comment: Is `MONTH(birthday)` sargable?

Comment: No, it's not, but then again converting the date to a string also is not sargable, and using ranges would not be practical, since the OP would accept any year (apparently).

Comment: Although if the OP is using MySQL 5.7.7+, with InnoDB, they could create an index on the month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really appreciate it and your answer solved my concern~